# How to set host header to server chosen by nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, load-balancing

`proxy_set_header Host            xxx;`

I want `xxx` to be the name of server chosen.

```
upstream myapp1 {
        server www.domainA.com:80;
        server www.domainB.com:80;
    }
```

so if **domainA** is chosen then `xxx` should be `www.domainA.com:80`..

Comment: [This post on the nginx forums](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,208188,208328#msg-208328) explains that what you attempt to do is impossible, because the request for the upstream is only made once.

Comment: Ok so only way left is to create proxy server that does load balancing in nodejs